# PHP Check if mysql database contains string in string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-like

So I have a database column where it has like past usernames.

This is what the row would look like if it had info.

```
bill, joe, ryan
```

What I am trying to do is check ever single row and check if like any of them contain joe. I have one possible theory on how to do it but what I fear is say someones past username is this:

```
billjoe
```

Im afraid it would think it exists in database because of that bill in it i would want it to ignore it if its not exactly bill.

Whats confusing is it could have for example 3 names in 1 string seperated by commas.

My theory on how to do it is like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE pastusernames LIKE :pastusernames");
$stmt->execute(array(':pastusernames' => "%bill%"));
```

But that may even be totally wrong. So is there anyway to do this correctly?

Comment: This might be easier if you normalize the database. Create a table `past_usernames` with columns `user_id` and `name`. Then you can search that table for the exact username and user_id.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how write in PHP. But the sql should look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE ', ' + pastusernames + ',' LIKE '%, bill,%'
```

adding the `,` you make sure the match the whole thing and not just a part

Comment: Shouldn't those `+`'s be dots (to concatenate)? I doubt "math" is being done here. Or, is this some guru SQL I don't know about? *lol*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I said was writing the sql code. Not sure how translate to PHP

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but may be below query may be work for you

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE pastusernames LIKE :pastusernames");
$stmt->execute(array(':pastusernames' => "bill"));
```